# Azure DevOps Pipeline create empty zip

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I would like to ask you how to solve a problem which I encountered during a creation of Azure pipeline.

Problem description:

Probably, "brick" responsible for building a project not create a bin folder so I finally get empty zip.
Despite of the fact all test were successfully completed(passed).

My yaml file:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.x'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/XXX.EvaluateFunction.csproj'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Evaluate.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'PortalArtifact'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Where are you specifying that the output location is `Build.BinariesDirectory`?

Comment: @DanielMann yes that was the case. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the document about [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services): `Build.BinariesDirectory` is the local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for compiled binaries. Your yaml file does not use it as an output folder so that this folder is empty. You can use `Build.BinariesDirectory` as an output folder in .NET Core task: `arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'`

Here is my complete sample:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        feedsToUse: 'select'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        publishWebProjects: true
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
       rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
       includeRootFolder: true
       archiveType: 'zip'
       archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Evaluate.zip'
       replaceExistingArchive: true
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

You can also refer to the sample about [create your first .NET Core pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=net%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser#create-your-first-pipeline-1).